# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

My **menu** was built using the wp **bootstrap** navwalker and everything is fine except the dropdown menu is not working. I have checked loading of jquery and **bootstrap.css** and **boostrap.js** order in the **functions.php** and everything looks correct. I've built several themes from scratch using this but I inhereted this website and I can't get it to work... 
Site is here if anyone can offer a suggestion --
http://rala.missionarydesign.net/

Comment: if i uncoment the code you have commented it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong `data-target` value in HTML. Update to following.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
```

Comment: Thank you! It was that coupled with the fact that I had two container ids. One outside the wp_nav_menu and one inside. I deleted the outside container and changed the data-target and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
   
   <div class = "navbar-header">
      <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
         data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
  
      <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">Example</a>
   </div>
   
   <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
 
      <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
         <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
   
         <li>
            <a href = "#" >
               Contact
              
            </a>
            
            
            
         </li>
   
      </ul>
   </div>
   
</nav>
```

Comment: can you please accept or comment this solution